# Work with google map

Tags: android, google-maps

Here is my code-

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


    <application

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When i save it , it shows an error regarding uses-library line.Why i am getting error in using uses library line? Anyone help me.

Comment: problem solved. i need to use that in my application tag.

Comment: you should accept answer, or write your own answer - so other users will find an answer fast if they will have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

The uses library should be under application tag... and you should paste your log so we could be more helpfull